# How to create priority Queries in JPA Repositories

Tags: java, mysql, spring, spring-data-jpa

I am trying to display a set of records from the database to view page by this query:

```
findByFirstNameOrSurNameAndGroupG_Name
```

but it does not work like what I expected!
I want it to work like : `(findByFirstNameOrSurName)AndGroupG_Name`

What is the correct syntax?

Comment: could always write a `query`

Comment: Use `@Query` !!

Comment: @AbdullahKhan this is only way? And can U give me an example to create a query in jpa?

Comment: Post your entities.

Comment: Not the only way. You can also use criteria builder but [@Query](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#jpa.query-methods.at-query) is less messy and will get you started pretty soon.

Comment: My entities: 
-First name
 @Column(nullable=false, length=45)
 private String firstName;
- Sur name
@Column(nullable=false, length=45)
 private String surName;
- Group:
@ManyToOne(fetch=FetchType.EAGER)
 @JoinColumn(name="groupId")
 private GroupG groupG;

Comment: Grouped clauses (those involving brackets) [are not supported](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#query-by-example.usage) by Spring Data method name parser.

Answer (score 0):

Unlike The Comments Given This Is Quite Achievable
The Only Downside Is Long Method Names And Repeated Arguments

It's Simple Math, You Can Combine Your Conditions Like This Using Equivalency

```
A /\ (B \/ C) <=> (A /\ B) \/ (A /\ C)
A and (B or C) <=> (A and B) or (A and C)
```

And Given The Fact That In Programming Conditions Using And ( && ),
First Condition To Meet Has More Priority (In Case Of && If First One Is False Others Are Not Checked And In Case || ( Or ) If First One Is True Others Are Not Checked);

**The First Properties You Start Your Method Name With Has More Priority**

As The Result Of Things That I Mentioned
You Can Achieve What You Want By This Method Name

```
findByFirstNameAndGroupG_NameOrSurNameAndGroupG_Name(String firstName, String groupName,String firstName2, String groupName2)
```

I Hope This Is Useful

Comment If You Need Further Help

Comment: This Question Is For 2 Years Ago, But I Encountered This Issue Recently. And Here I Am Answering It :)